# import a dataset with columns divided by blocks

Tags: r, import, dataset

I have a textfile dataset in ampl format and I want to tabulate this in m rows and n columns but this data is divided in blocks, ie the first *m* lines contains the first 19 columns, then again the same *m* rows are with the next 19 columns, etc., I tried to import this in R with `fread` from `data.table`, but I could only read the first block that is *m* rows with the first 19 columns. I put an example of the data

[Example dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kF_4wfmh55C--8COm9U3DRo3DeK6Nle-/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Some you can automate and sometimes you do a bit of manual inspection. 
Your data has a pattern, that is, `2 lines` above the start of your dataset are not properly formed (including the header which is a number). The same goes for every other block. The first column is also not part of the dataset. You don't need that into your dataset as well. So the easiest for you to do is to read the blocks with out the header and remove the first column, assemble them, and add a numeric header. That can be achieved as follows.

```r
df1 <- read.table(file = "dataset.txt", skip = 2, nrows = 100, header = FALSE)
# remove the first col
df1$V1 <- NULL

df2 <- read.table(file = "dataset.txt", skip = 104, nrows = 100, header = FALSE)
# remove the first col
df2$V1 <- NULL

df3 <- read.table(file = "dataset.txt", skip = 206, nrows = 100, header = FALSE)
# remove the first col
df3$V1 <- NULL

df4 <- read.table(file = "dataset.txt", skip = 308, nrows = 100, header = FALSE)
# remove the first col
df4$V1 <- NULL

df5 <- read.table(file = "dataset.txt", skip = 410, nrows = 100, header = FALSE)
# remove the first col
df5$V1 <- NULL

df6 <- read.table(file = "dataset.txt", skip = 512, nrows = 100, header = FALSE)
# remove the first col
df6$V1 <- NULL

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

mydf <- cbind(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6)
colnames(mydf) <- c(seq(1:100))
```

You might see a repeating pattern here which a function or a loop can be constructed, but I leave it at that for now.

Hope it helps.